# Correct way to implement paging for Cassandra with CassandraRepository from Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm looking for a solution to implement paging for our Spring Boot based REST-Service with a Cassandra (version `3.11.3`) database. We are using Spring Boot `2.0.5.RELEASE` with `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` as a dependency.

As Spring Data's `CassandraRepository<T, ID>` interface does not extend the `PagingAndSortingRepository` we don't get the full paging functionality like we have with `JPA`.

I read the Spring Data Cassandra documentation and could find a possible way to implement paging with Cassandra and Spring Data as the `CassandraRepository` interface has the following method available `Slice<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);`. I am aware that Cassandra is not able to get a specific page adhoc and always needs page zero to iterate through all pages as it is documented in the `CassandraPageRequest`:

> Cassandra-specific {@link PageRequest} implementation providing access to {@link PagingState}. This class allows creation of the first page request and represents through Cassandra paging is based on the progress of fetched pages and allows forward-only navigation. **Accessing a particular page requires fetching of all pages until the desired page is reached.**

In my usecase we have > 1.000.000 database entries and want to display them paged in our single page application.

My current approach looks like the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersResource {

  @Autowired
  UserRepository    userRepository;

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllTests(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", name = "page") @Positive int requiredPage, 
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "500", name = "size") int size) {

    Slice<User> resultList = userRepository.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.first(size));

    int currentPage = 0;

    while (resultList.hasNext() && currentPage <= requiredPage) {
      System.out.println("Current Page Number: " + currentPage);
      resultList = userRepository.findAll(resultList.nextPageable());
      currentPage++;
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(resultList.getContent());
  }
}
```

**BUT** with this approach I have to find the requested page while fetching all database entries to memory and iterate until I found the correct page. Is there a different approach to find the correct page or do I have to use my current solution?

My Cassandra table definition looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id int, firstname varchar, 
  lastname varchar, 
  code varchar, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

What I have done is to create a page object that has the content and the pagingState hash.

In the initial page, we have the simple paging

`Pageable pageRequest = CassandraPageRequest.of(0,5);`

once the find is performed we get the slice

`Slice<Group> slice = groupRepository.findAll(pageRequest);`

with the slice you can get the paging state

`page.setPageHash(getPageHash((CassandraPageRequest) slice.getPageable()));`

where

`private String getPageHash(CassandraPageRequest pageRequest) {
 return Base64.toBase64String(pageRequest.getPagingState().toBytes());
}`

finally returning a Page object with the List content and the pagingState as pageHash

Comment: What if I want to do paging on custom query for example: findUsersByNameInRange(String name, long startDate, long endDate);

Answer (score 1):

See this below code. It may help.

```
    @GetMapping("/loadData")
    public Mono<DataTable> loadData(@RequestParam boolean reset, @RequestParam(required = false) String tag, WebSession session) {
        final String sessionId = session.getId();
        IMap<String, String> map = Context.get(HazelcastInstance.class).getMap("companygrouping-pageable-map");
        int pageSize = Context.get(EnvProperties.class).getPageSize();
        Pageable pageRequest;

        if (reset)
            map.remove(sessionId);

        String serializedPagingState = map.compute(sessionId, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? null : map.get(session.getId()));

        pageRequest = StringUtils.isBlank(serializedPagingState) ? CassandraPageRequest.of(0, pageSize)
                : CassandraPageRequest.of(PageRequest.of(0, pageSize), PagingState.fromString(serializedPagingState)).next();

        Mono<Slice<TagMerge>> sliceMono = StringUtils.isNotBlank(tag)
                ? Context.get(TagMergeRepository.class).findByKeyStatusAndKeyTag(Status.NEW, tag, pageRequest)
                : Context.get(TagMergeRepository.class).findByKeyStatus(Status.NEW, pageRequest);

        Flux<TagMerge> flux = sliceMono.map(t -> convert(t, map, sessionId)).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
        Mono<DataTable> dataTabelMono = createTableFrom(flux).doOnError(e -> log.error("{}", e));
        if (reset) {
            Mono<Long> countMono = Mono.empty();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(tag))
                countMono = Context.get(TagMergeRepository.class).countByKeyStatusAndKeyTag(Status.NEW, tag);
            else
                countMono = Context.get(TagMergeRepository.class).countByKeyStatus(Status.NEW);
            dataTabelMono = dataTabelMono.zipWith(countMono, (t, k) -> {
                t.setTotalRows(k);
                return t;
            });
        }
        return dataTabelMono;
    }

private List<TagMerge> convert(Slice<TagMerge> slice, IMap<String, String> map, String id) {
        PagingState pagingState = ((CassandraPageRequest) slice.getPageable()).getPagingState();
        if (pagingState != null)
            map.put(id, pagingState.toString());
        return slice.getContent();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Cassandra supports forward pagination which means you can fetch first n rows then you can fetch rows between n+1 and 2n and so on until your data ends but you can't fetch rows between n+1 and 2n directly.